# Changing the Footer Code so that I can Sanitize and Linebreak our Store's Address at the same time?

Tags: html, footer, line-breaks, bigcommerce, sanitize

Our address on the footer of our BigCommerce Website has an apostrophe that shows up as [& #39;](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lYFDJ.png).

The current code looks like this:

```
<address>{{nl2br settings.address}}</address>
```

I tried replacing the code with this:

```
<address>{{{ sanitize settings.address }}}</address>
```

However it loses it's linebreaking formatting and I would like to keep that.

How would I combine the Sanitization of the code along with the linebreak functionality. Or is there a better way to go around this where I would get the same result?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like it may be a bug, Deo. I'd recommend you to report this to our Technical Support team by contacting them via live chat, phone or your preferred method listed here: https://support.bigcommerce.com/s/#contact